# Cannot Access Azure DB from powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to azure db and make several changes there from powershell.

```
$folder = "C:\Depl"
$connectionString = "Data Source=servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=configurationDB;User Id=username@servername;Password=Qwerty$5ok;Trusted_Connection=False;"
$dataTable = "[configurationDB].[dbo].[parameters]"    

$con = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection"
$con.ConnectionString = ($connectionString)

$sqlcmd = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand"
$sqlcmd.connection = $con
$sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 600000

$con.Open()

... other actions ...
```

I't used to work without any problem, but suddenly It started to fall with exception:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'username'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance."
At C:\Depl\ChangeParams.ps1:21 char:5
+     $con.Open()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

I have no idea what is happening, because I didn't change anything in .ps1 at all (It was setted almost a half year ago, and werent changed because I needed to run it only when I wanted to update some parametres).

I thought that 1433 port was blocked in firewall but... despite not able to connect from powershell, I can do it without any problem in SQL Server management.

Ant ideas what could be wrong? I ran out of them...

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks as if you did not replace 'username' in the connection string above.  Please see the following code for a [quick example](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-Hello-1cc5deb1) to compare/contrast with your code.

Comment: I thinked so, but this powershell script not working anymore on my PC, but I tried to run it from another and everything is fine. So, I guess something became broken... certificate or credentials, I dunno...

Comment: Does the reference sample script above work? Or do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have `$` in the user's password?

I had the same problem.

The symptoms were as follows:  I had two database servers; let's call call them "Server A" and "Server B". On "Server A", I tried to make a simple connection and the login succeeded, but on "Server B" I got the exception message:

> Error: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'XXXX'.
>   This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'.  Provide this tracing ID to 
>   customer support when you need assistance."

I suspected that I must have some configuration on Server B that must restrict the login process.

### Solution

My SQL user on Server B has `$` in password, and powershell uses the `$` character to introduce variables, so I had to prefix each `$` with a backquote character:

```
$Password = "Pa$$word"
```

must be replaced with

```
$Password = "Pa`$`$word"
```

Comment: Hi Toby, I edited my answer with a solution that solved my problem. I hope it helps you.